# SpringBoot can't find JSP (even with tomcat installed)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to use SpringBoot to display a .JSP page using embedded tomcat. Whenever I try to access the localhost URL, I get the Whitelabel Error Page with 404 Not Found. As you'll see below, I tried making a method for @RequestMapping to find the JSP location, to no avail. Previously, I was having issue importing Tomcat into pom.xml (was giving "not found" error). I fixed this by commenting out the `<repositories>` section in pom.xml, running it, then uncommenting it. How can I get my project to view .JSP files properly? I am following all steps in this Udemy course to a T. I will provide more info where needed.

- SpringBoot version is 3.0.0 M3
- My Java version is 18.0.1.1 2022-04-22
- I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3 Community Edition
- The JSP is called "sayHello.jsp" and it's located at `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp/sayHello.jsp` *(the file directory picture below shows this)*. It just has Hello World HTML code in it

> **pom.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-first-web-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-first-web-app</name>
    <description>My first SpringBoot web application from the Udemy Course</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build> <!-- Commenting/Un-commenting out <repositories> made it so tomcat-embed jasper dependency worked -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

> **SayHelloController.java** (directory of files pictured later below)

```java
package com.springboot.springbootfirstwebapp.hello;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class SayHelloController
{
    @RequestMapping("say-hello")
    @ResponseBody
    public String sayHelloDefault()
    {
        return "Hello! What are you learning today?";
    }

    @RequestMapping("say-hello-jsp")
    public String sayHelloJsp()
    {
        return "sayHello";
    }

    @RequestMapping("say-hello-html")
    @ResponseBody
    public String sayHelloOld()
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("<html>");
            sb.append("<head>");
                sb.append("<title>My first SpringBoot HTML page!</title>");
            sb.append("</head>");
            sb.append("<body>");
                sb.append("This is an HTML page with a body!");
            sb.append("</body>");
        sb.append("</html>");

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

> **application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

# For more information
logging.level.org.springframework=debug
```

> [The DEBUG log showing the 404 Not Found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4wHx.png)

> [My file directory in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4lMP.png)

Comment: I strongly suggest to not use JSP but something else like Thymeleaf. JSP have several restriction with embedded containers, one is that it only works with WAR packaging and not JAR packaging. There are more (which are mentioned in the reference guide).

Comment: @M.Deinum Good recommendation. I'm just trying to follow this Udemy course sharply so I can learn a certain way. I just want to try and get JSP working before I ultimately use Thymeleaf instead

Answer (score 0):

Your folder structure is wrong. Should be

`main -> webapp -> WEB-INF -> jsp -> sayHello.jsp`

[image: Floder structure]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Didn't work. Still gives the same whitelabel error 404 "No message available"

Comment: That is weird. I tested this again and I have it working. Ill update the answer with more details